# Sorting 2 lists that are related using zip function in Python, how to sort in descending order?

Tags: python

So, I am trying to sort 2 related lists. One contains Candidate Names, and one contains the Number of Votes the candidates have (candidate in `candidate[0]` has votes stored in `votes[0]`).

I found a way to sort votes[] in descending order, whilst keeping the indexes matched. For example if `vote[0]` becomes `vote[3]`, `candidate[0]` will also become `candidate[3]`. I did this using the built-in `zip` function, but the example I copied from sorted the lists in *ascending* order, whereas I require them to be sorted in *descending* order.
Here are my lists:

```
candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]
```

And to sort the lists I used:

```
votes, candidates = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates))))
```

This did exactly what I wanted, except in ascending order, not descending. How do I edit this to sort the lists into Descending order?

Comment: Those aren't `nested` lists, in fact aren't even lists

Comment: `sorted(zip(votes, candidates), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `reverse=True`:

```
candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]

votes, candidates = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates))))


print(sorted(votes, reverse=True))
print(sorted(candidates, reverse=True))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[9, 7, 3, 1]
['Mitt', 'Hillary', 'Donald', 'Barack']
```

OR

```
candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]

print(sorted(zip(candidates, votes), reverse=True))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('Mitt', 3), ('Hillary', 1), ('Donald', 9), ('Barack', 7)]
```

EDIT 3:

```
candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]

votes, candidates = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates), reverse=True)))

print(votes)
print(candidates)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[9, 7, 3, 1]
['Donald', 'Barack', 'Mitt', 'Hillary']
```

Comment: This outputs 2 lists, which is perfect. BUT, the lists are not in sync. Donald should be first, then Barack etc

Comment: @DaneBaird why should Donald be first if it is in descending order?

Comment: @DaneBaird check Edit 3.

Comment: Sorry about that, I realise I didnt specify which list I wanted to sort first! EDIT 3 is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You could just sort the `zip` of both the `list` and `reverse` it

```
>>> votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]
>>> candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
>>> 
>>> sorted(zip(votes, candidates), key=lambda x: x[0]) # in ascending order
[(1, 'Hillary'), (3, 'Mitt'), (7, 'Barack'), (9, 'Donald')]
>>>
>>> sorted(zip(votes, candidates), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True) # in descending order
[(9, 'Donald'), (7, 'Barack'), (3, 'Mitt'), (1, 'Hillary')]

>>> # and if you want it back in order again;
>>> votes, names = zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))
>>> votes
(9, 7, 3, 1)
>>> names
('Donald', 'Barack', 'Mitt', 'Hillary')
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it to output two lists, like unzipping it?

Comment: Sure. But why ? The dataset seems to be closely related ?

Comment: Anyway, here you go, `votes, names = zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))`

Answer (score 0):

Or, slicing for reversing:

```
candidates = ['Donald', 'Barack', 'Hillary', 'Mitt']
votes = [9, 7, 1, 3]
votes, candidates = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(votes, candidates))[::-1]))
```